# How to serve new DLLs directly from NuGet after each CI Build?

Tags: asp.net, build, nuget, nuget-package, package-management

I wish this is a stupid duplicate of an already answered question.

I have a asp.net website that depends on some other projects (dlls copied to bin). Now, what I want is every time any of those projects are updated, I get latest dlls in my website/bin. I DO NOT want my CI server to check-in updated dlls.

I already have a private NuGet feed for my project, and just want it to serve the latest dlls after each successful CI build. Now, my questions are

1. Is there a way to directly serve the dlls, without creating nupkg? And probably pick them from build output folder?  (for some reasons, it's not that convenient to create package as a post build task for all the dlls hundred times a day) If that is    possible, awesome!
2. If not, can we avoid increasing version number of dlls each time, still make nuget update to the new dlls? Something    like update based on latest publish date or something? (there is huge bunch of dlls, and lot of dependencies)
3. Is there a way to take latest dlls without building the solution? Yeah, I can do a nuget update command,    but is there any other way?

Someone suggested mirroring my current code base and using something like MyGet or ProGet. For several reasons, that is not feasible at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Triggering a Visual Studio build after any NuGet dependencies is probably not quite what you really need - that's a job for CI. However, you can set the version ranges in your packages.config file to make VS (via nuget) pull newer NuGet packages when available.

To answer your specific points:

1. Why would you want to server 'random' loose DLLs whose origin you cannot be certain of? NuGet provides a mechanism to track the origin of code on which your own code depends, which makes tracking down bugs easier :) If you rely on NuGet packages containing DLLs which change 'hundreds of times a day' then you should likely just build those DLLs directly with your application.
2. See #1 - if you are re-building NuGet packages very often, then you likely have your package boundaries wrong. Consider how truly independent your packages are, and see if it would makes sense to bring some of the DLLs together, or even separate out (fork) code which is shared between multiple separate applications. If you create a new version of a NuGet package, then you should increase the version number - that's a fundamental premise of semantic versioning, and you'll get into a mess if you do not follow this pattern.
3. To bring down the latest NuGet dependencies, `nuget update` is your friend :)

Using MyGet or ProGet *might* be part of a solution, but it's not directly related to the patterns you mention above.

Comment: The actual thing that I wanted to do is, every time my CI server runs successfully, it would push new nuget packages in my feed. So, I don't want to trigger VS build based on dependencies, but want to make new dll(s) available through nuget after each CI build.

Now that is possible by adding tasks in my build file to create new package after build. But, as you mentioned, creating new packages 'hundred times a day' is not probably a good option. So, I was looking for something so that

Comment: (1) dlls could be served directly, without creating package. Here, I'm very certain of the origins, as they are created from my (other) projects only. The purpose - devs get latest dependencies, each time they build their solution.
(2) what you said is true, I was just looking for a bypass for dev environment, where we can update packages based on build date or something, rather than increasing version each time (strictly dev)

Comment: One of the core principles of CI and especially Continuous Delivery is that any build *could* generate artifacts which could be pushed to production. This implies that you need traceability for all artifacts and builds.
If you find that you're building the dependencies (e.g. libraries) many times each day, then it's probable that you should bring this code into the main solutions which developers use.
You could try the `PreRelease` features of NuGet, although I still think that's not where your problems lie. M

Comment: Yes, there is the problem we have! Bringing that code as part of the main solution has always seemed the better solution, but there are some technical and non-technical constraints! So, was looking for a short cut to speed up internal dev process, but seems like NuGet is not yet ready for this domain. I'll keep looking for other way outs.

Comment: NuGet would be able to help here *if* you re-factored your code so that a single solution sits in a single repo :) I cannot recommend strongly enough that you solve the technical and non-technical challenges preventing that - it will definitely be worth it.